# Reversing Wye-Delta

Tags: transformer, step-up

I have edited both the title and the body of this question because my real world example was not being understood as it had a lot going on and I did not do an good enough job of making it concise. Let's make this a real simple test-like question... Last attempt before I have to draw a schematic...

You have a 480V 3-phase service as the input.

You have 3 individual, single-phase transformers with a nameplate that indicates they have both a 480V primary and a 480V secondary.

1. You configure all 3 together as a bank. You configure 3-phase Delta on the primary and 3-phase Delta on the secondary. What is your output voltage on the secondary?
2. If you left the primary of this bank configured as Delta and changed the configuration of the secondary to WYE, what would your secondary voltage be?

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you are proposing. Draw a picture showing the original configuration with another image of the proposed configuration.

Comment: This question skips over a lot of detail and uses shorthand, asking us to infer/assume way too much info. To start with, the exact voltage and configuration you want. What phase-neutral voltage? What phase-phase voltage?  Each transformer you mention in the first 2 sentences - voltage/phasing in, voltage/phasing out, and kVA.  And we need nameplate data and wiring diagram for the transformer you have, or links to a webpage that has all that.

Comment: My equipment needs 480 wye. I have 208 service in my building. I happen to have a transformer that I acquired that is a 480>208 delta-wye step-down transformer. For those of you that are familiar, you can reverse the transformer, so instead of being a step-down, it is a step-up. One of the downsides is that you are left with delta as that output, since it is inverted. My equipment can't deal with a high leg grounded delta as the output, I need a legitimate neutral. I'm looking to modify the transformer and rearrange the windings to be opposite of each other (delta in, wye out).

Comment: `What output does the transformer have now?` Driving same 480 V into former primary side *smoke*, so driven in reverse?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is not feasible as that would result in a transformer with a '3-N 830 V' output.

1. Original, step-down, 480 V : 208 V, delta-star transformer

[image]

2. Step-up, 208 V : 480 V, star-delta transformer

[image]

3. Modified, 208 V : 830 V, star-star transformer.

[image]

4. Modified, 120 V : 830 V, delta-star transformer is the same as 3 above, with the added drawback of 3 x 120 V supply not being available.

[image]

Comment: Are you assuming I'm connecting to a 480V input? My service is 208. I'm going to edit this question to simplify things.

Comment: No. The original transformer is as shown in serial no. 1. Serial no. 2 is with the windings  interchanged for primary and secondary. Serial no. 3 is with 3 x 208 V input giving 3 x 830 V output in star-star configuration. Serial no. 4 shows 3 x 120 V input giving 3 x 830 V output in delta-star configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Going from 480Δ/208Y to 208Δ/*same HV windings* Y should result in three times the voltage - if I got the English terms right and saturation&overcurrent didn't kill it.
(Both 480 V & 208 V are line-to-line voltages, low voltage winding voltage being 120 V?)

> Would the number of primary turns related to the core size be too far off?

Yes, if they fit now, the secondary become primary would see 208 V instead of 120 V.

> Winding gauge an issue?

You didn't disclose anything about the load but the voltage level and a *need for a legit neutral*.

Comment: Please refer to my added comment.

Comment: With three single phase 1:1 isolation transformers:  
1. ΔΔ: \$U_s = U_p\$, 2. ΔY: \$U_s = \sqrt 3 U_p\$, 3. YΔ: \$\sqrt 3 U_s = U_p\$, 4. YY: \$U_s = U_p\$.